# sql updating whole data in database

Tags: php, sql-update

I have written code to add and update users and also I want to add and update categories they can work in. The added users will go in users table and the categories they can access goes in the category_permitted table. I have the following code for adding and updating tables:

```
if ($user_info) {


if ($act == "add") {

if ($user_info) {
    $array = array(
            'user_id' => $user_info,
            'category_id' => $temp['cat_access']
    );

$category_permitted->addCategoryAccess($array);
}

} else {

if ($user_info) {

    $array = array(
            'user_id' => $id,
            'category_id' => $temp['cat_access']
    );

$deleteold = $category_permitted->deleteCategoryAccess($id);

$category_permitted->addCategoryAccess($array);
    }
}
    }
```

This my function to add and update category access:

```
public function addCategoryAccess($data, $is_die = false){

    return $this->insert($data, $is_die);

}

public function updateCategoryAccess($data, $id, $is_die = false){

    $args = array(
        'where' => array('user_id' => $id),
    );

    return $this->update($data, $args, $is_die);

}
```

And this is the data in database table [image: click here to see database].

My update function is updating all data of the column category_id with the number being added while updating category access for the user.

I want to leave 2 and 3 as it is and add another category id which is 1 but after running the update code it updates the data like this.[image: click here to see unexpected result] Do I have to add another condition to `WHERE CLAUSE` to get the expected output?

Comment: You should remove this update function and add a remove one, that way when a user can access a new category you add his id and category id in the table, when he can no more access a category you remove him (where user_id & category_id). To update just remove then add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in my code worked for me. I called the function `$deleteold = $category_permitted->deleteCategoryAccess($id);` just before the for loop to avoid deleting the previous data being deleted in every iteration.

```
if ($user_info) {

$cat_access = (isset($_POST['cat_access']) && !empty($_POST['cat_access'])) ? ($_POST['cat_access']) : $_SESSION['cat_access'];

$value = array();

if (!empty( $cat_access ) && is_array( $cat_access ) ) {

  foreach( $cat_access as $key => $item ) {

    $value[] = filter_var( $item, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

  }

}

$categoryData = $value;

$temp = array();

    if ($categoryData) {

        $count = count($categoryData);

        if ($count > 0) {

            $deleteold = $category_permitted->deleteCategoryAccess($id);

            for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

            $temp =array(

                'cat_access' => $categoryData[$i]

            );

            if ($act == "add") {

                if ($user_info) {
                    $array = array(
                            'user_id' => $user_info,
                            'category_id' => $temp['cat_access']
                    );

                $category_permitted->addCategoryAccess($array);
                }

            } else {

                if ($user_info) {

                    $array = array(
                            'user_id' => $id,
                            'category_id' => $temp['cat_access']
                    );

                $category_permitted->addCategoryAccess($array);
                }
            }

        }

        }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update only one row you need an *unique identifier* for that row.

If the column id is the primary key, you can use that column to update only the corresponding row.

```
$args = array(
    'where' => array('id' => $category_permitted_id),
);
```

As an alternative, if you know which category is changing, and the relation (user_id,category_id) is unique, you can add the changing category to the where.

```
$args = array(
    'where' => array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'category_id' => $category_id
    ),
);
```

**Please note** that i don't know your Database abstraction layer and i'm implying that you can simply add another entry in the array to put conditions in 'AND', this could be **wrong** in your case.

Managing relationships this way takes a bit of effort, and in my opinion is not worth it.
If you are able to modify the application logic, i suggest you to switch to using only insert/delete, like so:

- Add a permitted category: Just add it creating a new record with insert
- Remove a permitted category: Remove it trough a delete function
- Change a permitted category to another: Delete the one that is changing and add the new one

Comment: I have either delete or add in the column category_id of the user which already exists in the column user_id.

Comment: You can't have the expected results this way, because user_id is non unique, if you can't do the update based on an unique identifier (like `id` or the combination `user_id,category_id`), you can try deleting all category associated with `user_id` and reinserting the new ones, but to do so you have to bulk aupdate instead of single update at the application logic

Comment: Also, in your example, when you have categories 2 and 3, and want 1,2 and 3 instead, you have to perform an insert, not the update, so check if it's called the update method instead of the insert, maybe that's also a problem

Comment: I have updated my code and after calling `$deleteOld` I only get one data in `$temp['cat_access']`. But commenting `$deleteOld` I get all data in `$temp['cat_access']`.

Comment: Sorry, i can't help you more whitout context, can you add the var_dumps of the variables `$user_info`, `$id` and `$temp` to your question? Then I'll update my answer

Comment: `$user_info` will pass the id of the new user and `$id` will pass the `user_id` of existing user and for the `$temp` it passes the multiple values coming out from checkbox.